# Generate an id with fixed alpha numeric string and variable integer part php

Tags: php

I am trying to generate an id with fixed alphanumeric part and a varying 3 digit numeric part. 
That is, the id will look like:

```
LAB-SER-420316-1415-000
LAB-SER-420316-1415-001
...
LAB-SER-420316-1415-010
LAB-SER-420316-1415-020
...
LAB-SER-420316-1415-110
LAB-SER-420316-1415-210
.....
```

My task is to generate this id's only once, that is repeating id has to be avoided. Also once the page is loaded, it should generate single id.This is like giving a bill number or something like that. I've created a function to generate this string upto a limit. But I need it to generate everytime the page is loaded.

Code:

```
<?php
function generatebillno()
{
$saved="LAB-SER-420316-1415-";
for($count = 0; $count <= 999; $count++)
{
        $var= str_pad($count, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
        return $saved.$var; 
}

}
echo generatebillno();
?>
```

Can anyone help me to do this. I am stuck here..

Comment: In my mind, your most obvious solutions would be storing the last id in a cookie, a text file or a database, so that the next page load can read from the last stored id and increment accordingly. Is this what you're asking?

Comment: the ids will be stored in db?

Comment: Yes.. The id will be stored in db along with other details.

Comment: use session or cookie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this -

```
//fetch the max id (the last digit as number)
$sql = $mysqli->query('select max(cast(substring(demo_field, 21) as unsigned)) as digit, 

demo_field from demo');
$res = $sql->fetch_assoc();
//check for empty valyues
if (empty($res['demo_field'])) {
    $str = "LAB-SER-420316-1415";
    $res['digit'] = 0;
} else {
    $str = substr($res['demo_field'], 0, 19);
}
$dig = $res['digit'] + 1;
//add padding if needed
$dig= str_pad($dig, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
$newStr = $str.'-'.$dig;

var_dump($newStr);
```